# Visual Studio 2015 C# when typing it keeps going gray?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Whenever I attempt to write in VisualStudio2015 this occurs, where when I try to write, it works out fine for 1-3seconds, then the line I write on goes gray. It does not matter where I position my mouse, I tried with another keyboard to check if any keys were stuck, did not help.
This issue started to occur when I upgraded my PC to Windows 10. Tried several restarts etc.

Please help. This really gets annoying when trying to code :/

I am very bad at explaining my issue here, so please watch this gif to understand. Basically whenever I try to write, that line I am on grays out, leaving me unable to do so: https://gyazo.com/688a5660b29a3d93c0bb426715bcf038

[Issue shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0KG5.png)

Comment: At a first glance I don't see any "issue" in the screenshot... What exactly do you mean by *"it keeps going gray"*? What *"goes gray"* and where? Are you talking about the current line being highlighted?

Comment: Variables, fields and properties are gray-ish. Only classes are colored blue-ish. There is nothing wrong with this.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough, I find it hard explaining. When I go to a line and start writing it has this flashing line. After I write for 1-2seconds the line I attempt to write changes to gray, and the flashing line disappears. I am unable to write more, but I can still erase(backspace) whatever is on that line. Don't know what's triggering it

Comment: This is what I mean is happening:
https://gyazo.com/688a5660b29a3d93c0bb426715bcf038

Comment: Thanks for the screen capture :) Ok now that looks really strange, looks to me like the code editor window is loosing focus as soon as the intellisense (tries to) popup... Do you have/use any extensions for VS? If so, have you tried disabling all extensions and see if any of them is causing this?

Comment: Are you keep hitting CTRL+Space ? Looks like IntelliSense fails somehow and thus thinks its not a statement and delete the whole line...

Comment: I have no extensions, just basic C# that followed VS. I don't hit CTRL+Space, it happens on random occasions, after a few keys :/

Comment: You mean the line was highlighted in grey? try `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> General` and uncheck `Highlight current line`

Comment: Have you tried to delete the .suo file in your project? Then close VS and reopen it.

Comment: You can see in the GIF I added what the issue is. Tried to look for the so called .suo file, didn't find any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost a month I found out the issue was that my CS:GO was opened meanwhile, and it somehow interferes with my Visual Studio and other programs. Thanks for your help though.